# Upload 'ng build' to S3 Bucket

Tags: amazon-s3, angular-cli, github-actions, ng-build, building-github-actions

I am trying to upload my angular-meteor project's `'ng build'` to S3 Bucket.

This is my `.yml` file

```
on:
  push:
    branches:
    - dev

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v1
    - name: Setup meteor
      uses: meteorengineer/setup-meteor@v1
      with:
        meteor-release: '1.8.1'
    

    - name: Install Node.js
      uses: actions/setup-node@v1
      with:
        node-version: '10.x'

    - name: NG build Angular
      run: ng build --prod

    - name: Deploy to S3
      uses: jakejarvis/s3-sync-action@master
      with:
        args: --acl public-read --delete

      env:
        AWS_S3_BUCKET: ${{ secrets.DEV_AWS_S3_BUCKET }}
        AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
        AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
        AWS_REGION: ${{ secrets.AWS_REGION }}
        SOURCE_DIR: 'browser'
```

Once I run this, I am receiving this error message  for the `NG build Angular` section

[image]

Instead of running `ng build --prod` i have also tried to run `ng build — prod — aot`, `ng build -- --prod`  & `npm run build -- --prod` but Still I am receiving the same error message.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

By default GitHub runners won't have `ng/angular cli`. So we got to install it . Below piece of code should do the job for you.

```
on:
  push:
    branches:
    - dev

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v1
    - name: Setup meteor
      uses: meteorengineer/setup-meteor@v1
      with:
        meteor-release: '1.8.1'
    - name: Install Node.js
      uses: actions/setup-node@v1
      with:
        node-version: '10.x'

    - name: Install Angular CLI
      run: npm install -g @angular/cli

    - name: NG build Angular
      run: ng build --prod
    - name: Deploy to S3
      uses: jakejarvis/s3-sync-action@master
      with:
        args: --acl public-read --delete
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Now I am receiving this error message -

You have to be inside an angular-cli project in order to use the build command.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1

Comment: Try replacing `ng install` with below command. `npm install -g @angular/cli@latest`

Comment: thank you sam once again but I am still facing the same issue, see my followup questions - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68614368/receiving-error-while-try-to-build-angular-build

Answer (score 1):

`@angular/cli` is installed as a `devDependency`, so you have to use:

```
- name: NG build Angular
  run: npx ng build --prod
```

or in Angular 12+

```
- name: NG build Angular
  run: npx ng build --configuration production
```